# Help finding a second homogeneous polynomial of degree 5 that are also harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Essentially I have to find 2 homogeneous  polynomial of degree 5 that are also harmonic.

Knowing z=(x+iy) is analytic I found my first polynomial to be f(z)=z^5 and that multiples of this would polynomial would also satisfy this.

However I am unsure how I should approach finding the second polynomial.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve asks me to find two homogeneous  polynomials of degree 5 that are also harmonic. I found f(z)=z^5 but I'm not sure how to find a second polynomial that fit the above criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Analytic functions of $\bar{z}=x-iy$ are also harmonic (recall that $\Delta \propto \partial_z \partial_{\bar{z}}$, and the right-hand side can be written in either order, so a general harmonic function is $f(z)+g(\bar{z})$, $f,g$ analytic). Hence $\bar{z}^5$ should do.

---

Indeed, you can show there are only two such: considering the general homogeneous degree-5 polynomial in two variables gives
$$ p(x,y)= \sum_{r=0}^{5} a_n x^n y^{5-n}, $$
and in order for this to be harmonic, the Laplacian acting on it must give $0$. It is easy to see by explicit calculation that this corresponds to the four equations
$$ 20a_0 + 2a_2=0, 12 a_1 + 6 a_3=0, 6 a_2 + 12 a_4=0, 
 2 a_3 + 20 a_5=0. $$
One can check that the solution space is indeed the full $6-4=2$ dimensions, and each independent solution is a linear combination of the basic solutions that are the real and imaginary parts of $(x+iy)^5$.

Comment: The conjugate of a polynomial of $z$ is not a polynomial of $z$.

Comment: The question doesn't actually say it needs to be a polynomial in $z$.

Comment: How can one find all the homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ that is also harmonic?

Comment: Write $x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta$. Then $p(x,y) = r^n p(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ by homogeneity. $p$ can now be written as a polynomial in $e^{\pm i\theta}$. Put this into Laplace's equation and you find that the only suitable polynomials are $e^{\pm in\theta}$, i.e. when $p(x,y) = a (x+iy)^n + b(x-iy)^n$ for some constants $a,b$.

Comment: @Chappers That is very nice. I wrote down the polynomials for $n=3,4,5$ that satisfies Laplace's equation and noticed a pattern which is $p(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} x^k y^{(n-2)-k} ( (n-k)(n-1-k) a_k + (k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2} )$ where the coefficients of $x^k y^{(n-2)-k}$ has to sum to 0 in order for $p(x,y)$ to be harmonic.